# Lombok usage of 'val' type in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, lombok

Hi I'm using Project Lombok (version 0.11.2) in a project. I have both Intellij, and Eclipse (STS) installed, with lombok integrated with both IDEs (STS, via the lombok JAR, IntelliJ via the plugin [version 0.4, released 22/01/12]).

When I try to use the 'val' data type in IntelliJ, it fails to recognise the resulting types, however the same code works in STS.

Is this an issue with the IntelliJ plugin, or does the plugin just not support this feature?

val types were added in lombok 0.10.0, so are not a new feature.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

At this time, according to the [documentation](http://code.google.com/p/lombok-intellij-plugin/wiki/FeatureList) of the Lombok IntelliJ Plugin, this is not yet supported.

Disclosure: I am one of the core Lombok developers.

Comment: Wish it was. Lombok is a great helper.

Comment: Yes, the val feature pretty much force you to use Eclipse when you work on a project that use Lombok.

Comment: well, some good news: https://github.com/mplushnikov/lombok-intellij-plugin/issues/9